# Using Blender on an Azure VM

Tags: error, gpu, opengl

I really need to do some editing on a 3D model with some animations, but my PC would never run it, so I opted to use an **Azure VM** to try to run blender and maybe render the animation on the machine itself, which would be faster. I requested a quota increase to use the **NC8as_T4_V3**, which has the **NVIDIA Tesla T4 GPU**, and installed the NVIDIA drive extension on Azure... But when I try to open Blender, the error appears: A graphics card and driver with support for **OpenGL 4.3 or higher** is required.
Installing the latest driver for your graphics card might resolve the issue.

Comment: I know nothing about Azure, but you could try using Blender [version 3.6](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-6/) which has a slightly lower graphics requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you sorted this, but I'm looking in to set one up, and according to this page you need to install the drivers through the Azure portal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/ngads-v-620-series

(may not be the exact same VM type but I'd imagine a similar process is there for all)

> To take advantage of the GPU capabilities of Azure N-series VMs, NVIDIA GPU drivers must be installed.

> The NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension installs appropriate NVIDIA CUDA or GRID drivers on an N-series VM. Install or manage the extension using the Azure portal or tools such as Azure PowerShell or Azure Resource Manager templates. See the NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension documentation for supported operating systems and deployment steps. For general information about VM extensions, see Azure virtual machine extensions and features.

> If you choose to install NVIDIA GPU drivers manually, see N-series GPU >driver setup for Windows or N-series GPU driver setup for Linux for supported operating systems, drivers, installation, and verification steps.

Comment: I decided to try other VMs with video cards and I succeeded with one of them, I don't remember which one exactly, but I think it was nv12s_v3, I hosted it in Brazil and installed the drives, it has a Tesla M60 video card. It worked for me, but I needed more quotas.